# Possible ways for client to upload pictures with headings and text (non ecom)?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I am looking for possible ways to build a site where my client can easily upload his pictures with a heading / text and remove them again when needed, I prefer easy or quick solutions with high customization if possible.

**There is no e-commerce** on the page so it will essentially be a portfolio of sorts. **I do know a little bit of PHP and SQL**, but if the solutions require those I prefer it to be well documented, like a tutorial or such. My skills with html, css are fine, while java and jquery are okay, but a little limited.

I prefer not to work with wordpress, but if everyone thinks that would be the best option, then I will of course use that, though I am hoping for some alternatives.

I'd appreciate any input, advice or suggestions! **Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

Try to read about CMS.It will help you out.